# Getting the maximum array length quota in code behind...C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This is an MVC3 app. I have read and read and read but i cant figure this out. I am getting the max array length quota error when trying to upload a file to my server. I have gotten this before in my app, and fixed it by increasing it in the web.config.

```
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
```

Now im uploading documents via old school asmx services(because i have to, not my decision). I call the asmx services via WCF and i get the max quota error. I can download files that have  I uploaded the previous way i was uploading them (stream objects via WCF). So my question is not how do I fix this by changing values in config files, but how do i programatically get the max array length in C#. I wanna see what it is while i'm debugging. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.readerquotas.aspx

And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreaderquotas.aspx

The first explains where the property is stored. The second describes the property.